# Check if one list contains every element from second list

Tags: dart

Honestly I have no idea how to check if list 1 contains every element from 2nd list, but I need it.

EDIT:  i want to check if those 2 lists with same length have the same values, just with different indices

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide some examples of how your two lists can look like and what the expected result should be.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  final list1 = [5, 2, 3, 10, 2, 1, 11, 4];
  final list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  print(list1.toSet().containsAll(list2)); // true
}
```

Comment: i wonder if OP wants duplicates too - in that case `toSet` will not work

Comment: @pskink Well, it is just an example of two lists and it does not matter if they are sorted or not. OP does not specify any details about the objects but I expect the objects overrides `hashCode` and `==`.

Comment: i mean duplicates - in that case `toSet` will not work

Comment: @pskink That is correct. It does not check if you have the same amount of duplicates in the two lists. If that is the case, the example needs to be updated. I used the `toSet()` method to make the code somewhat efficient instead of looping though `list2` for every element of `list1`.

Comment: sorry, i want to check if those 2 lists with same length have the same values, just with different indices

Comment: @helloitsme3 Ok, but I expect my solution should also work for that case. If not, please tell me and I will make some adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to specify what you mean by "same elements". Do you mean *equal* elements (according to `==`) or *identical* elements (according to the `identical` function)? I'm going to assume `==`, since that's the most common, and if your elements don't override `==`, it's the same thing as identity anyway.

The simplest approach, if possible, is to sort both lists, then compare each element of one list to the element of the other list at the same position. That does require that the elements have an ordering that agrees with `==` (so `a.compareTo(b) == 0` if and only if `a == b`), and that you are allowed to change the ordering of the lists.

If you do almost anything else, you need to consider what happens if the same element occurs more than once in one of the lists.

Just comparing lengths as well is not enough, since `[1, 1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 2]` both have three elements, and all elements of either list is also an element of the other list. If duplicate elements can occur, you need to be *counting* the elements as well.

You can use [`UnorderedIterableEquality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/UnorderedIterableEquality-class.html) from `package:collection`. It implements a counting-based equality check on arbitrary iterables, which includes working on lists.

Example:

```dart
const unorderedEquals = UnorderedIterableEquality();
// ...
  if (unorderedEquals.equals(list1, list2)) {
    // ... lists have same elements ...
  }
```